# How to access local media file on my computer in JavaFX?

Tags: media, javafx

How to access local media file on my computer in JavaFX?

Here are the urls I tried:

`C:/PROJECT/videos/on2tm_352.flv`
`file:///C://PROJECT/videos/on2tm_352.flv` (suggested in some site forgot where)

It does play however, when I put the media file inside the project's folder and access it using `{__DIR__}/on2tm_352.flv`

Note: There are no exceptions and errors outputted. The screen is just blank.

KLite Codec 583 Mega, JavaFX 1.2, Netbeans 6.8 are used

Answer (score 6):

It is working right now for me:

```
private static final String MEDIA_URL = "file:/c:/Users/Alejandro/Downloads/oow2010-2.flv";
```

I tested it a few minutes ago....

or something like that:

```
private File file = new File("c:/Users/Alejandro/Downloads/oow2010-2.flv");
private final String MEDIA_URL = file.toURI().toString();
```

See you later =D

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
Media media = new Media(trackFile.toURI().toURL().toString());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

Answer (score 1):

By giving their URL to the Media?

Note that some issues with spaces in paths have been reported in the past, I don't know if it is still true.

[*EDIT following original message edit (URL examples)*]
First line isn't an URL, it is a path. Apparently the media player accepts paths as URL, but that's not the case for ImageView, though, so it is better to be strict.
Second line is correct.
Third line have a potential issue: `__DIR__` variables has already a terminal slash, so you should not add it, ie. write `{__DIR__}on2tm_352.flv` instead. Not sure if that's the issue (I haven't used much video yet) but worth trying.

Note that such URL (based on `__DIR__`) will point inside a jar file once the project is packaged.
It is OK in JavaFX 1.2, but for some odd reason, they chose to disallow such access in 1.3.

Comment: The url I supplied doesn't have spaces. Still it wouldn't work

Comment: @cancelledout: What URL? As long as you remain vague, answers will be generic... Do you have an error? Is your media file in a supported format?

Comment: Here it is:

I tried:
C:/PROJECT/videos/on2tm_352.flv
file:///C://PROJECT/videos/on2tm_352.flv (suggested in some site forgot where)

IT does play however, when I put the media file inside the project's folder and access it using {__DIR__}/on2tm_352.flv

There are no exceptions and errors outputted. The screen is just blank.

KLite Codec 583 Mega, JavaFX 1.2, Netbeans 6.8 are used.

Comment: TIP: What I usually do is create a java.io.File object with the path to the local file, then use "{File.toURI()}" as the location for the Media. Saves a lot of headaches trying to get the "file:" URL right. Also note, JavaFX 1.3 no longer allows media files to be loaded from jar files, so if your class is in a jar file, the "{__DIR__}" will not work because it will be a "jar://" url.

Answer (score 1):

I have found it easier to do the following with disk files. This relieves my feeble brain of determining all the rules for "file:" urls:

```
var file = new File("C:/PROJECT/videos/on2tm_352.flv");

Media {
   source: "{file.toURI()}"
}
```

I avoid using `{__DIR__}` for media as it can point to a "jar:" URL and that is no longer supported for media locations in JavaFX 1.3.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So if {__DIR__} is not supported, how can I access those files in a jar then?

Comment: Just to be clear {__DIR__} is supported. What is not supported is loading a media file from a Jar file. So, if {__DIR__} points to a jar file, the media will not load. For an explanation see http://www.javafx.com/faq/#5.3.

Answer (score 0):

You guys just have to specify the file's path as an URI path:

```
Media media = new Media("file:///C:/Users/David/Downloads/test.flv");
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

It's not required to instantiate a File at all.